# ffplay hwaccel mjpeg playback

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, hardware-acceleration

TL;DR: How can I play MJPEG stream from my WebCAM/HDMI Capture device via FFPLAY with hardware acceleration on Ubuntu 22.04 ?

Long Description:

I have some cheap HDMI capture devices that can output MJPEG stream with 1920x1080 resolution.

Here are the capabilities of one of my device: https://pastebin.com/9b0yXjEi

For a long time, I use following one-liner to play :

```
ffplay -fflags nobuffer -f video4linux2 -framerate 30 -video_size 1920x1080 -input_format mjpeg /dev/hdmi-rpi
```

This launches almost immediately in a few milliseconds, and uses %15 of a single core CPU + %9 GPU in my Ryzen 5700G.

But I wanted to go further and leverage HW acceleration. So I tried this:

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel vaapi -hwaccel_device /dev/dri/renderD128 -f v4l2 -framerate 30 -video_size 1920x1080 -input_format mjpeg -i /dev/hdmi-rpi -vcodec rawvideo -f matroska - | ffplay -i -
```

But this uses %29 CPU + %49 GPU ( Launches immediately as well)

And even more test with MPV:

```bash
stulluk ~ $  mpv --demuxer-lavf-format=video4linux2 --demuxer-lavf-o=input_format=mjpeg,video_size=1920x1080,framerate=30 av://v4l2:/dev/hdmi-rpi 
 (+) Video --vid=1 (mjpeg 1920x1080 30.000fps)
[ffmpeg/video] mjpeg: overread 8
VO: [gpu] 1920x1080 yuvj422p
V: 00:00:15 / 00:00:15 (99%)
[ffmpeg/demuxer] video4linux2,v4l2: Some buffers are still owned by the caller on close.
[ffmpeg] ioctl(VIDIOC_QBUF): Bad file descriptor
[ffmpeg] ioctl(VIDIOC_QBUF): Bad file descriptor
[ffmpeg] ioctl(VIDIOC_QBUF): Bad file descriptor

Exiting... (Quit)
stulluk ~ $
```

With above setup, MPV uses %13 CPU and %9 GPU.

So I want to know, if there a way to use HWaccel with FFplay so that I can reduce my CPU usage ?

And an addition: Is there a way to use new Vulcan renderer with MJPEG ? If so, how to compile FFmpeg and how to use it?